# How one can find the positive integer $k$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Let us consider the non constant complex analytic function $f$ on all $ℂ$ verifying

$$f(s)=(-1)^{k}f(2-s)$$

where $k$ is a positive integer.

My **question** is: How one can find the positive integer $k$.

Comment: What do you mean find $k$? Isn’t $k$ an arbitrary variable?

Comment: @RyanGreyling: $k$ is a constant not depend on $s$.

Comment: If $k$ is an integer, then only cases are possible: $f(s)=f(2-s)$ and $f(s)=-f(2-s)$. Both are satisfied by $f(s)=0$, for instance

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: The function $f$ is not a constant.

Comment: $k$ is even/odd iff $z \mapsto f(1+z)$ is an even/odd function. Both cases are possible, and I don't think that more can be said about it.

Comment: @MartinR: What about the complex logarithm.

Comment: If $f(s) = z(z-2)$ then $f(s)=-f(2-s)$. If $g(z) = z(2-z)$ then $g(s) = g(2-s)$ then $k$ may be anything...

Comment: @China: I  am not sure what you mean. The complex logarithm is not “an analytic function on all $\Bbb C$.”

Comment: @MartinR: I mean the use of the complex logarithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) to find $k$.

Comment: @China: Complex logarithm of what? $k$ is an integer, so $(-1)^k$ can only be $+1$ or $-1$.

Comment: @MartinR: The logarithm of  $f(2-s)/(f(s))$ if $f(s)≠0$

Comment: @China: I don't see how that helps. As I said, $(-1)^k$ can only be $+1$ or $-1$, depending on whether $k$ is even or odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $g(z) = f(1+z)$ to simplify the problem. Then the given identity is equivalent to
$$
g(z) = (-1)^kg(-z)
$$
and that holds exactly if

- $g$ is an even function and $k$ is an even integer,
- or $g$ is an odd function and $k$ is an odd integer.